# Wordpress Get Template URL

Tags: wordpress

I'm looking to return a template url rather than print it and  bloginfo('template_url');
prints... anyone know of a version of this function I can use inside of a string I'm building to print at a *later* point?

Example

```
    $html = '<td style="width:40px;"><img src="';
    $html .= bloginfo('template_url'); // <-- messes up string because it prints.
    $html .= '/images/pause.png"></td>';
    return $html;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend you use `get_template_directory_uri()` instead.

```
$html = '<td style="width:40px;"><img src="';
$html .= get_template_directory_uri();
$html .= '/images/pause.png"></td>';
return $html;
```

Read more about the method here: [Function Reference/get template directory uri, Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri)